# defective dll (using external function)

Tags: c++, dll

for some reason i need to write dll for a current program that for example have function A(), so i won't compile my dll, which calls this function, with out including implementation of this function(only providing header of it). And work with my dll in program, where this function implementation is. Is it possible, or i doing something critically wrong?

for example i want to run it like this:

main.cpp

```
#pragma comment(lib,"MyDll.lib") 
void A() { cout << "Hello world" } 
void main() {
HMODULE hLib;
hLib = LoadLibrary("MyDll.dll");
void (*pFunction)(void);
(FARPROC &)pFunction = GetProcAddress(hLib, "B");
pFunction();
}
```

main.h

```
 void A();
```

so in dll i want to write somithing like this:

```
void B() { A(); }
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's possible. Don't forget to `#include "main.h"` in your DLL source code.